# How to find content using PHP regular expression

Tags: php, html-parsing

I want to find content inside of a DIV. I just want to specify the DIV’s id; the rest is automatically adjusted under `preg_match`.
E.g.:

```
<div id="midbuttonarea" etc...>some text...</div>
```

Comment: Is there something which prevents you from using phps DOM-classes? It would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You're much more likely to get a good result using an HTML parser to parse HTML instead of Regex. It's extremely difficult to parse HTML with Regex, and the result may not be very reliable.

Check the accepted answer to this question: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html) for some suggestions on how to go about it.

Comment: it can be possible in php regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Brenton is right. Anyway, here you have:

```
<?php
   function findDivInnerHtml($html, $id){
      preg_match("/<div .* id=\"{$id}\" .*>(.*)<\\/div>/i", $html, $matches);
      return $matches[1];
   }
?>
```

Sample usage:

```
<?php
   $html = '<div id="other"> xxx </div>  <div id="midbuttonarea" etc...>some text...</div> ';
   $innerHTML = findDivInnerHtml($html, 'midbuttonarea');       
   echo $innerHTML; //outputs "some text..."
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Forgot to tell you that `$html` doesn't have to have line breaks. You can easily remove them with `str_replace` first